# Get all start-of-the-week dates between two dates

Tags: java, android, android-calendar, android-datepicker

I want to show the all week start dates between two dates.

Suppose, I have selected start date as `8th Dec 2015 - 30th Dec 2015`, then it should return the results:

```
6th Dec 2015
13th Dec 2015
20th Dec 2015
27th Dec 2015
```

Comment: Are you using the Java Calendar class or a date library such as JodaTime? The answer may vary, I'm just curious if you have a preference.

Comment: I am using Java Calendar class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library (or willing to switch to it), which is a personal preference of mine, you can use their [`dayOfWeek()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#dayOfWeek()) function to do this. It returns a `LocalDate.Property` object which you can then manipulate to get the [minimum value](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.Property.html#withMinimumValue()) (effectively being the start of the week).

To get the date you want and return the minimum date for that week, try this:

```
LocalDate myDate = getSelectedDate();
return myDate.dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue();
```

To get all dates until the end date, you can loop:

```
List<LocalDate> weekDates = new ArrayList<>();
LocalDate tmp = getFirstDate().dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue();
// Loop until we surpass end date
while(tmp.isBefore(getEndDate())) {
   weekDates.add(tmp);
   tmp = tmp.plusWeeks(1);
}
```